# I have given position margin-left margin-top tags on my code html css for desktop how can i delete it to my phone to make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, margin

## How can i delete some items based on the screen size ?

I have given at my css for desktop `margin-left`, `width`, `height`, and `position:absolute;` properties but I need them not to apply in mobile responsive.

How can I dot that ?

Comment: Just  use media queries, and try adding styles to their default such as  `position:relative; width: auto/fit-content; height: auto/fit-content; margin-left: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a **[media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries)**

In your case, you just want to add css code that applies for large screens so it would look like:

```
@media(min-width: <the-size-in-pixels-you-choose>px) {
    #my-id {
        margin-top: Xpx;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

To prevent certain CSS properties from applying in mobile responsive views, you can use media queries in your CSS. Media queries allow you to apply specific styles based on the screen size or device characteristics. By defining styles within a media query, you can control how your elements appear on different devices.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

Assuming you have a CSS class called `.my-element` with the properties `margin-left`, `width`, `height`, and `position: absolute;` that you want to exclude in mobile responsive views:

```css
.my-element {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Media query for mobile responsive views */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Empty block - properties inside here will not be applied in mobile views */
  .my-element {
    /* You can optionally reset the properties or simply leave it empty */
  }
}
```

In this example, we use a media query with the `max-width` property set to `767px`, which will apply the styles inside the media query block when the screen width is 767 pixels or less (typically corresponding to mobile devices).

Inside the media query block, we have `.my-element`, but it is empty, meaning none of the properties will be applied to `.my-element` in mobile responsive views. If you want, you can reset specific properties to their default values inside the media query block.

By doing this, the `.my-element` class will have its original properties applied on desktop views, and they will not be applied on mobile views due to the media query. This allows you to have different layouts and styles for different screen sizes.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT